# ReactJs : Setstate is not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the initial state which is assigned

```
state = {
            movie : null,
            actors : null,
            directors : [],
            loading : false
        }
```

Below is the set state which i set and at the end to set state as put in comment when it is set and not set. I'm not able to access the `this.state` outside.

```
this.setState({movie:result},() => {
                      //then fetch the actors
                      const endpoint= `${API_URL}movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
                      fetch(endpoint)
                      .then(result => result.json())
                      .then(result=>{
                        const directors =result.crew.filter((member)=> member.job==='Director' ); 
                        this.setState({
                            actors : result.cast,
                            directors,
                            loading : false
                        })
                       console.log(this.state); //here value is coming
                      })         
                  })console.log(this.state); //here value is not coming
```

How to get `this.state` value with updated info?

---

```
render() { 
    //removed code below mull div
    return  ( 
    <div className="rmdb-movie">
        {this.state.movie ? 
        <div>
          <Navigation movie={this.props.location.movieName}/>
        </div>  
         : null
        }

    </div> 
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is the result of using asynchronous functions. The callback you pass to `this.setState()` is called whenever the state is set, and there might be a delay between when you call `this.setState()` and when the state is actually updated. This means that the callback  may or may not be executed when you reach the second `console.log()`.

This explains why you are seeing these results. The first `console.log()` is actually called *after* the second `console.log`.

Comment: I undestood your comments, but wat to do to get update this.state value

Comment: It depends. Why do you want to access the updated values?

Comment: this is because state is having movie,actors, directors as null. So after calling API i need updated values

Comment: Ok then you want to access `this.state` inside of the callback function (i.e. where you are using your first `console.log()`)

Comment: actually i want to use in render function, but console.log(this.state) params is null

Comment: Could you explain why you want to access the state in `render()`? Odds are you don't need to. If you have a component that uses values from the state, React will update that component automatically when the state changes. You might want to update your question and add where and why you want to access the updated state, and what the render function looks like so other people can help you easier.

Comment: this is because i need to show page with data in render(), I have updated render function above

Answer (score 1):

This is react lifecycle ! The setState function is not executed instantaneously. The inner console.log prints the good values because in the callback of setState you are sur it is executed. The outer console.log is executed before setState has actually modified the state and so you don't see the updated info.

Comment: then how to fix this, i mean how can i get updated this.state with values

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is actually what is expected, this is because Javascript in general and your specific fetch API call is asynchronous. Your first console.log() is inside the response from the fetch request, so it is only executed when the server returns the response(which could be a few seconds or more), then the state is set, then you print using console.log. The second console.log is outside, and will actually print instantly ,even before the async API call is made, before the state has actually been updated. Therefore, I would recommend that whatever action you want to do after the state is set, should be done where the first console.log is. Or preferably like this in a callback that you can pass to this.setState to ensure the state has been updated.

```js
this.setState({movie:result},() => {
                      //then fetch the actors
                      const endpoint= `${API_URL}movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
                      fetch(endpoint)
                      .then(result => result.json())
                      .then(result=>{
                        const directors =result.crew.filter((member)=> member.job==='Director' ); 
                        this.setState({
                            actors : result.cast,
                            directors,
                            loading : false
                        },()=>{
                        // API Call has returned and state has been updated
                        // Now access this.state 
                        });
                      })         
                  })
```

Answer (score 0):

setState operation is asynchronous, you can read more about it in [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

What problem are you trying to solve? Probably you need to use hook [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or just use this value in next render call.

Comment: I am trying to achieve to get updated this.state with updated params

Comment: What business problem are you solving? Do you need to render view with updated data or show popup?

Comment: React will call render function after setState, so just check for data in render function like `if (this.state.data) return <SomeComponent data={this.state.data}>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink the code because there is no way result will get to movies the way you put it. Except somehow you update another state inside the API function to fetch movies. So somehow you can call fetch which you must have binded to your class 
this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this) from some onclick or onchange or something.

```
fetch =() =>{

        const endpoint= `${API_URL}movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
        fetch(endpoint)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result=>{
          const directors =result.crew.filter((member)=> member.job==='Director' ); 
          this.setState({
              actors : result.cast,
              directors,
              loading : false,
              movies:result
          })


        }) 

  }
```